# -[UINavigationItemView playbackStateChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting this message the second time i run through a piece of code, but not the first. Why can it not find a method which it had no problem finding previously? Here's the code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
```

And the method is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure, that UINavigationItemView doesn't have playbackStateChanged:. Ergo, if it works first time and later not, there must be an instance of another class first, that vanishes later and gets replaced with an instance of UINavigationItemView — a classic over-release/under-retain.
Probably you are also not unregistering the observer from observing in dealloc or viewDidUnload.